# deploy rest api in ec2 and serve through https

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, https

I'm new to AWS and I'm in the process of deploying an app there. I already hosted my frontend in S3 and cloudfront and generated a certificate in order to serve my frontend with https. Now I need to provide access to my backend. I already created the proper structure in EC2 and I can even retrieve info from my backend through simple http. The problem is that once my frontend is https and my backend is http it refuses to receive info thowing an error for "mixed content".
I already read a lot of articles from AWS and yet I'm confused on how to implement https in ec2.
I've created load balancers, VPC and etc, but I really can't make it work.

If anyone can help me with , I'd be thankful!

Comment: Do you use API Gateway for your REST API?

Comment: No, actually I have seen  some coments about it, but I didn't realize how it works yet

Comment: Could you tell us more about your backend structure ? Which application server, components, language used for API etc...

Comment: I'm using NodeJS with express for the api, mysql for the database and serving it on ec2 as mentioned... any info in specific I didn't provide and you consider important please let me know.